# Collabnet Subversion Tortoise svn

Tags: apache, svn, tortoisesvn, collabnet

I have installed Collabnet subversion 1.6.15  with tortoise svn 1.6.12, I have made some changed in `httpd.conf` file to redirect to the access-authz folder, after making necessary changes Collebnet subversion service (Apache) stopped working. and I am not able to access my repository on TortoiseSVN.

Comment: Subversion 1.6.12 is very old (it was released like 10 years ago at the time of writing). Whatever, Apache is still Apache. What do you get then you run `httpd -t` and what do the error logs show?

Answer (score 0):

1. Subversion 1.6.x is ancient. You need to use Subversion 1.10.x or newer.
2. Consider [installing VisualSVN Server](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/getting-started/) that provides intuitive admin interface as well as advanced repository web UI. VisualSVN Server installs in a next-next-finish manner and you don't need to configure it manually via editing the httpd.conf files.